# My active session won't load, returns WSOD - CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm working on an assignment and ran into this weird problem.

So say I enter a username/password and am now logged in. I go to a different website, and want to return back to the webpage I was logged into. This is how I implemented taking care of that situation:

```
//Controller

public function index()
    {

        $loggedin = $this->alibrary->is_loggedin();


    if ($loggedin === false) 
    {
        $this->load->view('normal_screen');
    }

    if ($loggedin === true)
    {
        $this->load->view('homepage');
    }
}
```

But if I have previously logged in and return to the webpage I get a blank screen. But when I'm not logged in it displays the normal screen. I don't know why I'm getting a blank page, could someone please explain? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be my personal preference but I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
public function index()
{
   $loggedin = $this->alibrary->is_loggedin();

   // redirect non logged in users to another page
   if (!$loggedin) {
        redirect('your/url/to/normal_screen', 'location');
   }

   // If they get this far we can assume they are logged in, so load the view
   $this->load->view('homepage');

}
```

You'll notice I use `redirect()` when the user is not logged in. My personal preference is to redirect non-logged in users back to the login-in screen if they attempt to access a part of the site that requires authorization.

Comment: Thanks boss, I didn't use the code above, instead your previous comment helped me as the code above would load both views (normal_screen and homepage) for some reason. I used an if/else statement. Thanks again